Automatic car just stalled while trying to park and now just cracking not won't start
2021Kia Seltos petrol DCT with ~20K km. Just stalled on me when I was trying to park after driving it for 30km. It was just cracking but not moving. So, turned off the engine and tried to restart. It is just cracking but not moving. What could be the problem?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What year is your Kia? What is the mileage on it?


Mileage is ~20K km


Are you trying to use the word "cranking" in stead of "cracking"? If not, I have no idea what you mean by "cracking" ... (figured this might be an autocorrect error going on?)
